# pyspark ignore row if the column type is having some regex pattern

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json format  data file, one of its field exists as string as well as struct type

when it is a string

```
"class":{"student":"{\"one\":\"one\"}"}
```

when it is a structure

```
    "class": {
        "student": {
            "name": ["aaa"],
            "subject": ["a", "b"],
            "regular": true
        }
    }
```

now I want to drop the row when the value is of type string.

In specific I want to drop if the values has '\' this symbol and convert other rows to json struct type. so that I can access particular value as **"class.student.name"**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dataframe is called `df` and your column `col` this filters out the rows you don't want:

```
df = df.where('cast(col as string) not rlike "\"')
```

Comment: okay, now other rows I want to convert from string to json, since pyspark read proper json field also as string, I want to convert to json filed